# Android Tab Help. How to set 2nd tab as default when app opens?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have created an app with 3 tabs. The app works fine but I want the 2nd tab to be selected and loaded when the app opens. How can I set that?

Here is my code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();



        // Tab for Home
        TabSpec homespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        homespec.setIndicator("Home",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_home_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        homespec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Child
        TabSpec childspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Child");
        childspec.setIndicator("Child",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_child_tab));
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
        childspec.setContent(homeIntent);

        // Tab for Account
        TabSpec accspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Account");
        accspec.setIndicator("Account",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_account_tab));
        Intent accIntent = new Intent(this, AccountActivity.class);
        accspec.setContent(accIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(homespec); // Adding home tab
        tabHost.addTab(childspec); // Adding child tab
        tabHost.addTab(accspec); //Adding account tab
        }
```

Comment: tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); as your tabs are 0-1-2

Comment: val tabs = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabs)
tabs.getTabAt(1)!!.select() in kotlin (1 can be any index of your preference)

Answer (score 13):

Use this method to set the current tab after you added tab in tabHost

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);  // here pass the tab index its starting from 0
```

Answer (score 3):

use `tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);` in your onCreate

Answer (score 1):

```
public override void OnResume() 
    {
        base.OnResume();
        tabHost.CurrentTab = 1; //index of the tab you want to set to default.
    }
```

Override the OnResume() and assign the CurrentTab property of tabHost to the index of the tab you want to.

Comment: tabHost.setCurrentTab() within the OnResume method worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There are some difficulties if you have fragments. The hack is to make tab selection delayed. See **[code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52752853/1112963)**.