# Tabbed Activity to open 2nd tab on startup

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tabbed activity on Android Studio.I want to open my second tab on startup.How can i do this?

[image]

Comment: This solution solved my problem ;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796710/tablayout-tab-selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using viewpager then you can simply do

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(n);
```

where, `n = tab` no which you want to open as default.

Since it counts from index `0` so in your case `n=1`, so it will be

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(n);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tabHost then you can simply do-

tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

just after you set the tabHost in onCreate()

Comment: no, im not using tabHost, im using standat tabbed activity mechanizm.