# how can i solve android tab layout switching

Tags: android

i am developing an android app which has four fragments with tablayout and each fragment has connection error dialog box.

- first problem is,when i start my app,four fragments work
  simultaneously at the same time.So,when i occur connection error four
  dialog boxes are shown in first fragment When i switch to second tab
  it doesn't show his dialog box because his dialog is shown in first
  fragment.
- second problem is,i create that fragments with swipe refresh layout
  to fetch data from server.I call onRefresh method in onCreate method.
  when i start my app,first fragment data is loaded from server but
  when i switch first tab to second tab,it is not loaded his data from
  server but when  i switch first tab to third tab,it is work.
  Also,when i switch second tab to third tab,it is not loaded data from
  server but when i switch second tab to fourth tab,it is work. It is
  only work when i switch tabs with one tab differ. Is there anyway to
  solve that problems.

I searched this problems from internet but i didn't get my problems answer.
Please anyone help me.Thanks in advance.....
Sorry for my poor english

> this is tablyout code

```
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpagerMain);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayoutMain);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Noticeboard"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("News"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Events"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Result"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

> **This is MyAdapter class**

```
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        int num_of_tab;

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int num_of_tab) {
            super(fm);
            this.num_of_tab = num_of_tab;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    NoticeBoardFragment noticeBoardFragment = new NoticeBoardFragment();
                    return noticeBoardFragment;
                case 1:
                    NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();
                    return newsFragment;
                case 2:
                    EventsFragment eventsFragment = new EventsFragment();
                    return eventsFragment;
                case 3:
                    ResultFragment resultFragment = new ResultFragment();
                    return resultFragment;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return num_of_tab;
        }

    }
```

Comment: First Problem: you need to check the connection error in Onresume() method instead of oncreate().

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796710/tablayout-tab-selection Solve your quesion by this link

Answer (score 0):

Override setUserVisibleHint in each fragment and write your dialog box code in if(isVisibleToUser) instead of Oncreate. This should solve your problem

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);




    if(isVisibleToUser) {

     //dialog box code here 


     }

}
```

Comment: but my dialog box is created in another class.How can i call it.

Comment: i shared as an answer

Comment: Write this method in FragmentActivity.
 public Fragment getFragment(int position){

 Fragment fragment = (Fragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager,position);
if (fragment instanceof  NoticeBoardFragment){NoticeBoardFragment object = (NoticeBoardFragment) fragment;

            return object;
        }else if(fragment instanceof EventsFragment){
            EventsFragment object = (EventsFragment) fragment;
            return object;
.. Pass an unique int FRAGMENTAG along with the network call and call the Dailogalert from each fragment