# How to highlight tab of the TabLayout programmatically independently of the tab indicator position

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I try to **highlight tab of the TabLayout** programmatically with this code:
`tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getCustomView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f44336"))`

But it isn't working, I don't why...

I will be so grateful for your help)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TabLayout tab selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796710/tablayout-tab-selection)

Comment: I marked this is a duplicate- I think the answer should help, let me know if it doesn't meet your needs!