# Tablayout - Setting tabs to start from right side

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How do I set it so that tabs start from the right side of the layout?

Like this layout:

[image]

I've tried using

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
app:tabGravity="center"
```

but that just centers it, not starting it from the end.

```
 app:tabGravity="fill"
```

Causes it to go to the left side, but I want to to go to the right.

Here's my tablayout

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/activitypayment_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicator="@null"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/PaymentTabLayoutStyle"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/dividerColor"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBlackFont"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test1" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test2" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Other" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to your TabLayout
and add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the android manifest file

Comment: Just tried, doesn't seem to work. I tried with center as well as fill. https://i.imgur.com/Rx4kSHn.png

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796710/tablayout-tab-selection) - i assume you are trying to gain focus on the last tab.

Comment: No that's not it

Answer (score 0):

There is an Easy way what you can try in your **Main**:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

and set whatever tab you want to be your default;